# awesomium: processing java-script click makes no sense

Tags: c#, javascript, awesomium

Here is the code I run (webcontrol on WPF):

```
private void htmlClick(string action) {
    if (this.webControlGroove.IsDocumentReady) {
        this.webControlGroove.ExecuteJavascript(
            String.Format(
                @"document.getElementById('{0}').click();", action));
        }
    }
```

I can see that my action gets into string in correct way and when I run `document.getElementById('myElement').click();` in chrome console I can see result

But when I run it in awesomium that just makes no sense. Why? How can I debug it?

Comment: This is pretty old question (for sure based on older Awesomium version), but did you solve it?

Comment: @voytek no, even if question is old I still remember that it was very big problem in using awesomium for me